# how to fix package not found (render pipelines)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

An error occurred while resolving packages:
Project has invalid dependencies:
com.unity.render-pipelines.high-definition: Package [com.unity.render-pipelines.high-definition@12.1.0] cannot be found
com.unity.render-pipelines.universal: Package [com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@12.1.0] cannot be found
com.unity.shadergraph: Package [com.unity.shadergraph@12.1.0] cannot be found

A re-import of the project may be required to fix the issue or a manual modification of manifest.json file

how to fix guys ?
my version unity 2021.3

Comment: Did you reimport like it said?

Comment: how to do it ??

Comment: Remove it. Then readd it. Like anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar issues with my unity editor (v2021.3), I had to do a fresh install of unity. Step 1: Uninstall the editor + hub through control panel, Step 2: Press Start (windows key) + R and type the following > %appdata% <, hit enter then delete, Unity, UnityHub, press the start button (windows key) and search recycling bin, open it and empty it.

Should work

Comment: do i have to re-download unity? is there any other way than that?

Comment: you might be able to find a work around, but that is the way that worked for me

Comment: okay, I will find another way first, if not I will use your way

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar issue with Unity v2021.3.11f1 after importing the Terrain Tools and Sample Assets into my URP project:

```
Project has invalid dependencies:
    com.unity.render-pipelines.high-definition: Package [com.unity.render-pipelines.high-definition@12.1.0] cannot be found
```

The solution is to close Unity, open the manifest.json file (ProjectName\Packages\manifest.json), which lists all project dependencies, one per line. Find the line that contains the invalid dependency, delete, ensure each line is still ended with a comma, save the file, open Unity and error should be gone.

Hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same problem, my solution is simply to go to "package manager" in "unity registry", and update all the updatable packages, especially the "High Definition RP" and "Shade Graph", then the error is disappeared.  :)

Comment: I updated these packages in "Packages: In Project" section of Package Manager.

Answer (score 2):

In the project you want to upgrade to the Universal Render Pipeline, open the Package Manager window, change the Packages dropdown to Unity Registry, then search for Universal RP and click Install.

Answer (score 2):

just go to the package manager then update the pipeline it will fix it
it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Just delete this line "com.unity.visualeffectgraph": "12.1.8", from
(ProjectName\Packages\manifest.json),
for my case (D:\Rifat\Unity Learning\Creative Core\Animation\Packages\manifest.json).

I hope you find this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Mine error popped up when I downloaded Unity sample project, it specifically said what version of unity it should ran on, however I did not want to download it, so I changed the unity version in Unity Hub (to one I had downloaded earlier) and on startup I got the package cannot be found.

If you also downloaded the project from somewhere and your version of Unity mismatches I recommend to update the packages to versions your Unity version supports, rather then reinstalling whole unity or completely removing the package as that could break the project.

Also I will add, the safest option is to actually run it on the correct version as the other version could introduce some breaking changes, but you can first try just downgrading or upgrading the URP package version (for you actually the HDRP) and see what happens.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error and the only thing that works for me is going into *Help Menu> reset packages to default*